# Rearranging js to accommodate more flexibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent

How can I make this js affect only the child elements of the original hovered element without giving all of the individual .g_scroll or .left/.right tags id's?

```
function loopRight(){
      $('.g_scroll').stop().animate({scrollLeft:'+=20'}, 'fast', 'linear', loopRight);
  }

  function loopLeft(){
      $('.g_scroll').stop().animate({scrollLeft:'-=20'}, 'fast', 'linear', loopLeft);
  }

  function stop(){
      $('.g_scroll').stop();
  }


  $('#right').hover(function () {
     loopRight().children();
  },function () {
     stop();
  });

  $('#left').hover(function () {
     loopLeft();
  },function () {
     stop();
  });
```

JSfiddle for (confusing, but necessary) html structure: https://jsfiddle.net/6rbn18cL/

To demonstrate how it would have to be renamed: https://jsfiddle.net/z9u3azqy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here, I "merged" both arrow handlers.
Then, there is a calculation needed to determine the "scroll" speed, based on width to be scrolled, which may no always be 100% of the element's width.

This script allows you to easily determine a speed for 100% scrolling.
Then, it calculates the speed if there is already a distance scrolled.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function moveit(arrow){

    // Adjust you delay here
    var delay = 2000; // delay to scroll 100%
    var animationDelay;

    var slider = arrow.siblings(".g_scroll");
    var distance = slider.width();
    var scrolled = slider.scrollLeft()+1; // +1 is to avoid infinity in the math below

    if(arrow.hasClass("scroller_l")){
      distance = -distance;
      animationDelay = -distance * (-distance/delay)*(-distance+scrolled);
    }else{
      animationDelay = distance * (distance/delay)*(distance-scrolled);
    }

    slider.stop().animate({scrollLeft:distance}, animationDelay, 'linear');
  }

  function stop(arrow){
    arrow.siblings(".g_scroll").stop();
  }


  $('.scroller_l, .scroller_r').hover(function(){
    moveit($(this));
  },function() {
    stop($(this));
  });

}); // ready
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/owWzdP?editors=0010)

---

**--First answer--**

First, you can't use the same `id` more than once.
So I removed `id="left"` and `id="right"` from your HTML.

Now the trick is to pass which arrow is hovered to your functions, using `$(this)`.
And find the `.g_scroll` element which is a sibling of it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  function loopRight(arrow){
    arrow.siblings(".g_scroll").stop().animate({scrollLeft:'+=20'}, 'fast', 'linear', loopRight);
  }

  function loopLeft(arrow){
    arrow.siblings(".g_scroll").stop().animate({scrollLeft:'-=20'}, 'fast', 'linear', loopLeft);
  }

  function stop(arrow){
    arrow.siblings(".g_scroll").stop();
  }


  $('.scroller_r').hover(function(){
    loopRight($(this));
  },function() {
    stop($(this));
  });

  $('.scroller_l').hover(function(){
    loopLeft($(this));
  },function() {
    stop($(this));
  });

});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PjmZaM?editors=0010)

Comment: This looks great! Only problem now is that the hover is being triggered to stop prematurely - any ideas?

Comment: It scrolls + or - 20 px... You could set it to the slider width as in this [CodePen v2](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yXbaYY?editors=0010)

Comment: almost perfect! Now the speed resets every time I scroll a certain amount. ie when the remaining slider width is shortened the speed is adjusted. Before it was looping 20px - is there a way to replicate this behaviour?

Comment: Here is another [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/owWzdP?editors=0010)... In an attempt to "simplify" the code... The results look more complex (lol) but it does what you want. ;)

Comment: Dude - amazing, nice work. I can see I still have far to go with js! I would never think of using it like this. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the event object and find the proper container from there.

```
$('.scroller_l').hover(loopRight, stop);
$('.scroller_r').hover(loopLeft, stop);
```

This is done automatically if you pass functions as parameters like the above.

To find the scrolling container dynamically for each instance you can use the classes to find the container relative to the current target:

```
var el = $(ev.currentTarget),
    parent = el.closest('.country_holder'),
    container = parent.find('.g_scroll');
```

See a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/josburL8/).

At this point you can ask yourself whether `loopRight` and `loopLeft` can be combined in one function. The only difference is the '-=20' and '+=20'.
With polymorphism you can refactor this even further.